# css3 animation not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a small animation that is working in firefox, but not in webkit browsers. Maybe someone sees the mistake cause i've looked for an hour... It is part of a impress.js presentation, similar to prezi. 
Thanks!

css:

```
#its.step.present h5{

display: inline-block;
position:absolute;




 animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
 -moz-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
 -webkit-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
 -ms-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
 -o-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;

-moz-animation-delay: 4s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
-ms-animation-delay: 4s;
-o-animation-delay: 4s;
animation-delay: 4s;


}
@-moz-keyframes aia2{
    0%{

        left:120px;
        -moz-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg);
        transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg);

        color: red;
    }
    90%{
        left: 580px;

        -moz-transform:scale(1) rotate(2000deg);
        -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(2000deg);
        -ms-transform:scale(1) rotate(2000deg);
        -o-transform:scale(1) rotate(2000deg);
        transform:scale(1) rotate(2000deg);

    }
    100%{
        left: 580px;


    }
}
```

html:

```
<div id="its" class="step" data-x="850" data-y="3000" data-rotate="90" data-scale="5">
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li>Web Development,</li>
                <li>Web Design,</li>
                <li>Log<h5>o</h5>&nbsp;&nbsp; Design,</li> 
                <li>Web Marketing,</li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="doua">
                <li><h6>e</h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Commerce,</li>
                <li>CMS (WP, J, D),</li> 
                <li>Cust&nbsp; m Apps</li> 
                <li>and others.</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: If someone wants to see the animation... http://www.messagelab.ro/pages/Presentation.html#/its  The o and e should move, as in firefox...

Comment: do you have the `@-webkit-keyframes aia2{` rules for Chrome?

Comment: good point :) so it is redundant to write inside -moz-keyframes {-webkit-transform..} ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have to put the general animation rule **after** the browser specific ones:

```
-webkit-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
   -moz-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
     -o-animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate;
        animation: aia2 5s linear infinite alternate; /* this comes last */
```

And since you have `-webkit-animation: aia2`, `-moz-animation: aia2` etc. you have to set the animation for each browser like:

```
@-moz-keyframes aia2{
    ...
}

@-webkit-keyframes aia2{
    ...
}
@-o-keyframes aia2{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Chrome v43 dropped the -webkit- prefix for animation so if this worked before but not now, that's probably why.

Comment: So what is the solution, if you want to do webkit-keyframes-zoominDwn and zoomoutdown in google chrome?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to check if you're developing in Firefox is Firefox will take an animation-name in quotes, but Chrome/Edge/Safari/Webkit will not.

**Acceptable ONLY in Firefox:**

```
animation-name: 'theAni';
```

**Acceptable in all browsers (Chrome, Edge, Safari & Firefox):**

```
animation-name: theAni;
```

Answer (score 0):

for each property that you want add animation you need first determine its value then you can change it in keyframe.

here is a simple code that you can try it:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
      <style>
           #forTest {
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: darkcyan;
                width: 500px; /* here we determine the value of property that we want add animation */
                height: 30px;

                animation: a1;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-duration: 5s;
           }

           @keyframes a1{
                to {
                     width: 100px;
                }
           }
      </style>
 </head>
 <body>
      <div id="forTest"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Hi hi Welcome :) Could you add more detail to your answer? I'm not really familiar with css3 but I got the feeling the OP might not get what you're saying just from that

Comment: I tryed again.hope its useful.