# CSS Keyframe Animation Not Working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations, css-transforms

I've got an css keyframe animation set on a background div with a lot of going on—3d transformations, opacity, color, etc. The animation worked perfectly fine in Chrome a couple months ago, but doesn't seem to work now. It still works great in Safari.

Essential code related to the problem below; [full code/live site here](http://brianmetcalf.com/); *note that the transformation is overtaking by mouse movement as well(this works fine in Chrome + Safari).

Sry, please don't hate me for my poop and sexytime naming conventions ;)

HTML

```
<div class="background-container"  id="poop">
        <div class="background-movement">
        </div>
</div>


<script>
    var element = document.getElementById('poop');
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        var transform = 'rotateX('+e.pageY*.05+'deg) rotateY('+e.pageX*.02+'deg)';
        element.style.webkitTransform = transform;
        element.style.transform = transform;
    }, false);      
  </script>
```

CSS

```
       .background-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .background-movement {
            background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
            z-index: 100;
            position: absolute;
            top: -50%;
            left: -50%;
            width: 200%;
            height: 200%;
            background-repeat: repeat;
            background-size: 500px;
            -webkit-animation: sexytime 60s ease-in-out 0 infinite alternate;
            animation: sexytime 60s ease-in-out 0 infinite alternate;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes sexytime {
            0% {    
                opacity: 1;
                -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg) brightness(.8);
                -webkit-transform-origin: left;
                -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate3d(10, 0, 0, 20deg);   
            }

            20%{
                -webkit-transform:scale(1.3) rotate3d(20, 30, -10, 40deg);
            }

            40% {
                opacity: .9;
                -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(60deg) brightness(1);
            }

            50% {
                opacity: .8;
                -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(300deg) brightness(1.3);
                -webkit-transform-origin: top;
                -webkit-transform:scale(1.3) rotate3d(70, 10, 30, -10deg);              
            }

            60% {
                opacity: 1;
                -webkit-transform:scale(1.3) rotate3d(10, -40, 0, 30deg);   
            }

            80% {
                opacity: .9;
                -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-30deg) brightness(1.3);
                -webkit-transform:scale(1.3) rotate3d(20, 30, -20, 30deg);  
            }       

            100% {
                opacity: 1;
                -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(120deg) brightness(1);
                -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
                -webkit-transform:scale(.9) rotate3d(30, -10, 50, 20deg);
            }   
            }

        @keyframes sexytime {
            0% {    
                opacity: 1;
                filter: hue-rotate(0deg) brightness(.8);
                transform-origin: left;
                transform:scale(1) rotate3d(10, 0, 0, 20deg);           
            }

            20%{
                transform:scale(1.3) rotate3d(20, 30, -10, 40deg);
            }

            40% {
                opacity: .9;
                filter: hue-rotate(60deg) brightness(1);
            }

            50% {
                opacity: .8;
                filter: hue-rotate(300deg) brightness(1.3);
                transform-origin: top;
                transform:scale(1.3) rotate3d(70, 10, 30, -10deg);                  
            }

            60% {
                opacity: 1;
                transform:scale(1.3) rotate3d(10, -40, 0, 30deg);   
            }

            80% {
                opacity: .9;
                filter: hue-rotate(-30deg) brightness(1.3);
                transform:scale(1.3) rotate3d(20, 30, -20, 30deg);  
            }       

            100% {
                opacity: 1;
                filter:hue-rotate(120deg) brightness(1);
                transform-origin: bottom;
                transform:scale(.9) rotate3d(30, -10, 50, 20deg);
            }   
            }
```

Comment: If this is copied verbatim, you have an unfinished property: `-webkit-transform-origin-z:` at 0% in your webkit keyframes. The property is not present in your unprefixed keyframes.

Comment: For what it's worth, nothing happens in Firefox either, so it's probably not specific to Chrome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265096/css3-animation-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: Took out the webkit origin z.
The above link doesn't seem to answer my problem. I have the webkit + general animation rules in the correct and same order.

Comment: Also, is this not a webkit problem as I originally thought? Since chrome + safari run webkit?

Comment: Figured it out—the webkit aniamtion need an "s" after the 0 for delay. 
   `-webkit-animation: sexytime 60s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;`