# @keyframes not working in chrome desktop (IE/Chrome mobile all OK)

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

I'm trying to create a scrolling photo banner. It is working on IE, safari (mobile), and chrome on android and iphone. It is not working on my desktop or if I request desktop site on any chrome device. I've spent hours googling trying to figure this out and cannot work it out at all. 
This is my first time asking a question so if something is wrong in my post please bear with me. Thank you

```
#container {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 5px;
background: white;
}

.photobanner {
height: 350px;
width: 3550px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.photobanner img {
margin: 10px;
max-height: 300px;
margin-top: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}


      /*keyframe animations*/
.first  {
-webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
        animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes "bannermove" {
0% {
margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
margin-left: -2125px;
 }

}


@-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -2125px;
 }

}


    /* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 750px) {#container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    background: white;
}
.photobanner {
height: 160px;
width: 3550px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

.photobanner img {
margin: 5px;
max-height: 150px;
margin-top: 5px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the HTML and/or putting a workable amount of code on https://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: HI, Apologies I've not used jsfiddle so hope this link works.... https://jsfiddle.net/Emylou/6am9qnfa/ Many thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried with keyframes without quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer is not coming too late, but I just fixed an issue similar to yours so thought I would share my solution.

1. Put your general animation rule after the browser specific ones. See this answer ([css3 animation not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265096/css3-animation-notworking-in-chrome)).
2. You may need to open your website in an "incognito" tab! Stylesheet changes may not update immediately due to browser cookies.