# Why is my CSS animation not smooth in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I created this animation that works fine in Safari and Firefox but not in Chrome. When I run it in Chrome, it skips frames in the animation. It basically looks like it's lagging but there's no way it is. I left the background-image property empty in the code below but in reality I'm using an image that's about 244kb.

Here is my class:

```css
.splatImage{
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    -webkit-animation-name: splatImage;
    animation-name: splatImage;
    opacity:1;
    height:85vh;
    /*background-image:url("");*/
    background-color: blue;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    margin-top:8vh;
    
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.3s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 1.3s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    
    visibility: visible !important;
    }

    # this is my keyframes animation:
    @-webkit-keyframes splatImage {
    0%{
        opacity:0;
        height:45vh;
        top:0;
        margin-top:25vh;
    }
    95%{
        opacity:0;
        height:45vh;
        margin-top:25vh;
    }
    96%{
        opacity:1;
        height:45vh;
        top:0;
        margin-top:25vh;
    }
    100%{
        height:85vh;
        margin-top:8vh;
        opacity:1;
    }
    }

    @keyframes splatImage {
    0%{
        opacity:0;
        height:45vh;
        margin-top:25vh;
    }
    95%{
        opacity:0;
        height:45vh;
        margin-top:25vh;
    }
    96%{
        opacity:1;
        height:45vh;
        top:0;
        margin-top:25vh;
    }
    100%{
        height:85vh;
        margin-top:8vh;
        opacity:1;
    }
    }
```

```html
<!-- and I just use it in a simple HTML div: -->
<div class="splatImage"></div>
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. I read it might have something to do with Chrome having issues with CSS animations since version 40 but I'm guessing those bugs have been fixed by now.

If there's a way to simply have the animation ignored by Chrome I could use that too.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: HI check this ticket, it might give you a hint on how to get this bug fixed, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265096/css3-animation-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: That did not help at all. If you look above, You'll see I already made sure the general animation property was placed after the specific one, -webkit-.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce your problem. https://jsfiddle.net/70newakg/1/ . This works properly for me

Comment: It likely appears to be jagged, probably because all dimension computations boils down to the pixel: there is no subpixel height or width that you can declare. This means that the smallest transitionable unit will be in full pixels, instead of subpixels compositing made possible using `transform` for example.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle and share, i checked it and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Ok I tried creating a jsfiddle right now and I used a URL for my image source and that ended up working smoothly. I created two test files one for CSS and one for HTML to see if I would get the same issue in separate files and I still did. Then I changed the source for the image in the test files I made to the URL I used on jsfiddle instead of the image I created on my computer and it was smooth. So it appears there's something wrong with my image that it does not transition well on Chrome. It's a simple png file, not sure what's happening here.

Comment: So I tried making my image size smaller and that fixed my issue. Thanks everyone for offering help. Testing with jsfiddle and having to use a different image source gave me a new perspective. I really didn't think an image that was less than 1mb would be a problem but clearly I was wrong. Thanks again.